# Encoding used in cast from char to byte

Tags: c#, character-encoding, casting

Take a look at the following C# code:

```
byte[] StringToBytesToBeHashed(string to_be_hashed) {
    byte[] to_be_hashed_byte_array = new byte[to_be_hashed.Length];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (char cur_char in to_be_hashed)
    {
        to_be_hashed_byte_array[i++] = (byte)cur_char;
    }
    return to_be_hashed_byte_array;
}
```

(function above was extracted from [these lines of code from the WMSAuth github repo](https://github.com/Softvelum/wmsauth/blob/2de04369ee73fad2ca5ef8d6a67d2e5b136a2811/src/authorize_plugin/UrlProcessor.cs#L78-L84))

My question is: **What the casting from byte to char does in terms of Encoding?**

I guess it really does nothing in terms of Encoding, but does that mean that the Encoding.Default is the one which is used and so the byte to return will depend on how the framework will encode the underlying string in the specific Operative System?

And besides, is the char actually bigger than a byte (I'm guessing 2 bytes) and will actually omit the first byte?

I was thinking in replacing all this by:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToBeHashed)
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The .NET Framework uses Unicode to represent all its characters and strings. The integer value of a char (which you may obtain by casting to `int`) is equivalent to its UTF-16 code unit. For characters in the Basic Multilingual Plane (which constitute the majority of characters you'll ever encounter), this value is the Unicode code point.

> The .NET Framework uses the `Char` structure to represent a Unicode character. The Unicode Standard identifies each Unicode character with a unique 21-bit scalar number called a code point, and defines the UTF-16 encoding form that specifies how a code point is encoded into a sequence of one or more 16-bit values. Each 16-bit value ranges from hexadecimal `0x0000` through `0xFFFF` and is stored in a `Char` structure. The value of a `Char` object is its 16-bit numeric (ordinal) value.  — [Char Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx)

Casting a `char` to `byte` will result in data loss for any character whose value is larger than 255. Try running the following simple example to understand why:

```
char c1 = 'D';        // code point 68
byte b1 = (byte)c1;   // b1 is 68

char c2 = 'ń';        // code point 324
byte b2 = (byte)c2;   // b2 is 68 too!
                      // 324 % 256 == 68
```

Yes, you should definitely use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Casting between `byte` and `char` is like using the [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encoding (= the first 256 characters of Unicode), except it silently loses information when encoding characters beyond U+00FF.

> And besides, is the char actually bigger than a byte (I'm guessing 2 bytes) and will actually omit the first byte?

Yes.  A C# `char` = UTF-16 code unit = 2 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

`char` represents a 16-bit UTF-16 code point. Casting a `char` to a `byte` results in the lower byte of the character, but both *Douglas* and *dan04* are wrong in that it will always quietly discard the higher byte. If the higher byte is not zero the result depends on whether the compiler option *Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow* is set:

```
using System;
namespace CharTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {   ByteToCharTest( 's' );
            ByteToCharTest( 'ы' );

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void ByteToCharTest( char c )
        {   const string MsgTemplate =
                "Casting to byte character # {0}: {1}";

            string msgRes;
            byte   b;

            msgRes = "Success";
            try
            {   b = ( byte )c;  }
            catch( Exception e )
            {   msgRes = e.Message;  }

            Console.WriteLine(
                String.Format( MsgTemplate, (Int16)c, msgRes ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Output with overflow checking:

```
Casting to byte character # 115: Success
Casting to byte character # 1099: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
```

Output without overflow checking:

```
Casting to byte character # 115: Success        
Casting to byte character # 1099: Success
```

Comment: Maybe in some weird environment it does throw, but I think in most environments that case doesn't throw. I have tested in my local "Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1590.0" and in repl.it: https://repl.it/Irlw/1 . And both return success on both cases (no exception like your output shows).

Comment: @Mariano Desanze, I can't tell about Mono, but how can MS convert it without error if their own reference source clearly shows that the input character is [compared](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,fc990bd1275d43d6)(on line 725) to `Byte.MaxValue` before conversion, and an exception is thrown if the char's value does not fit into a byte?

My environment is not strange—it is plain-vanilla .NET 3.5 .

Silent discardment of the higher byte is a bad idea

Comment: Got it: I had the *Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow* option on in SharpDevelop. So the result of this conversion is ambivalent, i.e. depends on the compiler settings!

Comment: In that case sorry for the downvote. I'll revert it if you edit your answer, as I cannot otherwise (maybe you can clarify that it won't throw on every environment). But this is really strange, because even on the online interpreter at  https://www.microsoft.com/net you can put `char c = 'ы'; Console.WriteLine((byte)c);` and see it returning "75" instead of an exception.

Comment: I have edited the answer—thanks for the feedback. Looks like overflow checking is off by default.