# Difference between using Encoding.GetBytes or cast to byte

Tags: c#, encoding, byte

I was wondering if there's any difference between converting characters to byte with `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` or manually using `(byte)` before characters and convert them to byte?

For an example, look at following code:

```
public static byte[] ConvertStringToByteArray(string str)
{
    int i, n;
    n = str.Length;
    byte[] x = new byte[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        x[i] = (byte)str[i];
    }
    return x;
}

var arrBytes = ConvertStringToByteArray("Hello world");
```

or

```
var arrBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello world");
```

Comment: Have you tried it with encoding different than UTF8?

Comment: @wudzik No, I used UTF8 only.

Comment: C# encodes string in quotes as UTF8 so converting it by using `(byte)` is same as `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`.

Comment: See below discussion:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708548/encoding-used-in-cast-from-char-to-byte

Comment: @wudzik actually a .NET string is UTF16, so it would not be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I liked the question so I executed your code on an ANSI text in Hebrew I read from a text file.

The text was "שועל"

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"d:\test.txt");
var arrBytes = ConvertStringToByteArray(text);
var arrBytes1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
```

The results were

[image: This is what I got in the watch]

As you can see there is a difference when the code point of any of your characters exceeds the 0-255 range of `byte`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ConvertStringToByteArray` method is incorrect.
you are casting each `char` to byte. `char`'s numerical value is its Unicode code point which could be larger than a byte, so the casting will often result in an arithmetic overflow.

Your example works because you've used characters with code points within the `byte` range.

Answer (score 1):

when wanna cast characters that have encoding, you cant use first one, and you must say chose encoding standard

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a difference. All .Net strings are stored as UTF16 LE.

Use this code to make a test string, so you get high order bytes in your chars, i.e chars that have a different representation in UTF8 and UTF16.

```
var testString = new string(
    Enumerable.Range(char.MinValue, char.MaxValue - char.MinValue)
    .Select(Convert.ToChar)
    .ToArray());
```

This makes a string with every possible char value. If you do

```
ConvertStringToByteArray(testString).SequenceEqual(
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(testString));
```

It will return `false`, demonstrating that the results differ.